# How to compute the Monotonicity value of a list or array in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an array or list, and I would like to compute the Monotonicity value.
I am aware that Pandas has built-in functions such as :
pd.Series(mylist).is_monotonic_increasing
pd.Series(mylist).is_monotonic_decreasing

and the output is boolean (True or False).
However, I am interested in the value that's between [0,1].
Therefore, my question is not whether the list or array is monotonic.
my question is: by how much is the list or array increasing or decreasing?
The answer should be a value between [0,1].
Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Can you give a small sample Series and your expected answer?

Comment: Eg. [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4]   i know this is a monotonically increasing list. I'm not interested in computing (True or False). I'm more interested in an output such as (0.132)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
np.diff(mylist).mean()
```

Or skip the mean and you will have the increment on each step

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @RichieV. previously, i used this                                        
mon=(max(x)-min(x))/(len(x)-1) and the value i got is almost similar to yours. I'm not sure this is the right way. Any advice?

Comment: That works only if your list is monotonic, i.e. it always goes in the same direction

Comment: Thank you @RichieV. I have seen also some academic papers in which they use the following formula to compute monotonicity:                                                                     Mon = l Number of PosValues - Number of NegValues l / k-1                                                     in which k is the len of the data. How would you express this in python? and, how about when the data doesn't contain Neg values?

Comment: `vals, freq = np.unique(np.sign(np.diff(mylist)), return_counts=True)`